# How do I sort with Lodash sortBy?

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I've an array like the one below and I'm trying to sort the items in the array by its price using lodash, but I don't see it working. Please let me know what is wrong here, as per the lodash documentation it will take an array and should return the sorted array.

My data

```
var items= [
  {
    "total": 11,
    "productGroup": {
      "_id": "5834754f0acc770ce14b1378",
      "name": "Auto Biography",
      "description": "Yum",
      "type": "book"
    },    
    "_id": "58791af46c698c00475e7f41",    
    "price": 200,
    "sold": 0
  },
  {
    "total": 11,
    "productGroup": {
      "_id": "5834754f0acc770ce14b1378",
      "name": "Science Fiction",
      "description": "Yum",
      "type": "book"
    },    
    "_id": "58791af46c698c00475e7f41",    
    "price": 120,
    "sold": 0
  },
  {
    "total": 11,
    "productGroup": {
      "_id": "5834754f0acc770ce14b1378",
      "name": "Language",
      "description": "Yum",
      "type": "book"
    },    
    "_id": "58791af46c698c00475e7f41",    
    "price": 125,
    "sold": 0
  },
  {
    "total": 11,
    "productGroup": {
      "_id": "5834754f0acc770ce14b1378",
      "name": "Fiction",
      "description": "Yum",
      "type": "book"
    },    
    "_id": "58791af46c698c00475e7f41",    
    "price": 300,
    "sold": 0
  }
]
```

Sort code

```
items = _.sortBy(items, item=>{return item.price});
```

Comment: What is it doing instead?

Comment: What version of lodash are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you're using an older version of Lodash. It works with 4.17.2 as demonstrated below.

```js
var items = [
  {
    "_id": "58791af46c698c00475e7f41",    
    "price": 200
  },
  {
    "_id": "58791af46c698c00475e7f41",    
    "price": 120
  },
  {
    "_id": "58791af46c698c00475e7f41",    
    "price": 125
  },
  {
    "_id": "58791af46c698c00475e7f41",    
    "price": 300
  }
];

var results = _.sortBy(items, item => item.price);
console.log(results);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.2/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @ruakh thanks, I've updated the answer to include that

Comment: I've updated my answer to include a working snippet. Most likely it's the version of lodash.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [source code](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/4.17.4/lodash.js#L9946), the second argument should be an array of iteratees. To fix the problem you need to put your anonymous function inside an array, e.g.

```
items = _.sortBy(items, [item=>{return item.price}]);
```

Comment: Please expand on this answer to show an example of the correct implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the response everyone, but unfortunately even after modifying my code as above it is still not returning the sorted array, it is giving me back the array as is.